# How to store data from MsSQL in my application (easy to use)

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

I'm currently writing my first WPF application. It provides a GUI for viewing, editing and creating data from my mssql-server. In my database I have one main table and a couple of sub-tables (foreign keys in main table).In my view, I have a Datagrid to Display all the data. I have several other views, that can add, edit and delete rows in my main table and in some sub-tables.

In a first version of my Programm, I had a public static class which contains several `public static ObservableDictionarie`s (from [Dr. WPF](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/)), with the ID-Columns of my Database as key and a custom type as value. These dictionaries had the same structure as my database. With the start of my program I filled all of this static dictionaries and then I can access them at any time from anywhere in my code. The controls in my views I bound with `x:static`.

The problem I have now, is that I can't use INPC with this static class, so my GUI doesn't update when I e.g. delete rows of my dictionary. When I change the data inside a row the GUI updates, because I implemented INPC in my custom type.

So how can I store the data in my application in an easy way? This is only a small application with only one programmer, so I think that patterns like MVVM is a bit too much for this (and I used this never before). For example I use the events of controls in code-behind. But I want to use the comfort of binding my DataGrid to a dictionary and the INPC to update my GUI.

Sorry for my bad english, but my native language is german.

Comment: When you delete rows set the datasource of your DataGrid to null and then back to your ObservableDictionary.  Setting to null will force the GUI to refresh and display the updates.

Comment: Yes, that works. I did this already in the past. But then I always have to remember to do this. I hoped there is an easy way that does it automatically. Also i've read a thousand times, that static classes (and singletons) are evil. But how to store the data then, without every time read it from MsSQL again?

Comment: It is not that static classes are evil, it it the net library is missing a lot of functionality and back doors need to be used.  The issue here is how to send an event to the paint event method to update a GUI when data changed.